# Use Linq for a Database call with Entity-Framework and navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 4 DB Tables and they have a foreign Key with a 1:n relationship. The order is like following

DbTable1 -> DbTable2 -> DbTable3 -> DbTable4

I use the entity framework and the Tables are in my edmx. Therefore I can use the navigation.

My linq call to get the data looks like this

```
     var dbContext = table1
                    .Where(w => w.table2.table3.table4.DbValue1 == value1 &&
                                w.table2.table3.table4.DbValue2 != value2 &&
                                w.table2.table3.table4.DbValue3 == value3 )
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        Result1 = s.Value1,
                        Result2 = s.Value2,
                        Result3 = s.table2.table3.Value1,
                        Result4 = s.table2.table3.table4.Value1
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

My question is now if this navigation call is good practice? Because the code readabillity is a bit worse, even more if the table names are very long. Is there a better way to do this? I know there is another variant with join but I like this navigation variant.

Hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a spoonful of syntactic sugar and use the `let` clause:

```cs
var result = 
(
    from w in table1
    let tab4 = w.table2.table3.table4
    where tab4.DbValue1 == value1 &&
          tab4.DbValue2 != value2 &&
          tab4.DbValue3 == value3
    select new
    {
        Result1 = w.Value1,
        Result2 = w.Value2,
        Result3 = w.table2.table3.Value1,
        Result4 = tab4.Value1
    }
).ToList();
```